# Need help with screen resloutions

Tags: resolution

So My screen resolution is off my screen because I use a TV so I use a custom screen resolution 1824x1026 is what I use.  While I try to set it to that resolution I get these messages:

```
brian@brian-desktop:~$ cvt 1824 1026 60
# 1824x1026 59.94 Hz (CVT 1.87M9) hsync: 63.84 kHz; pclk: 155.25 MHz
Modeline "1824x1026_60.00"  155.25  1824 1936 2128 2432  1026 1029 1034 1065 -hsync +vsync
brian@brian-desktop:~$ xrandr --newmode <modeline>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
brian@brian-desktop:~$ xrandr --newmode "1824x1026_60.00"  155.25  1824 1936 2128 2432  1026 1029 1034 1065 -hsync +vsync
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  16 (RRCreateMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  39
  Current serial number in output stream:  39
brian@brian-desktop:~$
```

also using hdmi-0 output as well if that helps anyone
Any help would be appreciated thanks.

When i xrandr

```
brian@brian-desktop:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
1280x720       60.0 +   59.9  
1920x1080      60.0*    59.9     30.0     30.0  
1360x768       60.0  
1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
800x600        75.0     72.2     60.3     56.2  
720x480        59.9     30.0  
640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9     59.9  
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
1680x1050_60.00 (0x2b6)  146.2MHz
    h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
    v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
1824x1026_60.00 (0x2ba)  146.2MHz
    h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
    v: height 1059 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
1824x1026_60.00 (0x2bb)  146.2MHz
    h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
    v: height 1059 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
1280x720_60.00 (0x2c3)   74.5MHz
    h: width  1280 start 1344 end 1472 total 1664 skew    0 clock   44.8KHz
    v: height  720 start  723 end  728 total  748           clock   59.9Hz
brian@brian-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Have you tried other resolutions, like `1680x1050` or `1280x720`? And are you trying to get both screens to show the same display/ have the same resolution?

Answer (score 0):

You can run `xrandr` for a list of available resolutions. Here is the example output for a Laptop:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: i need a custom one so it fits on screen the ones that i have options to set for dont fit on screen (im using a tv/hdmi)